# Where are environment variables stored in the Windows Registry?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, registry

I need to access an environment variable remotely. To do this, I think the best way is to read it from registry.

Where are environment variables stored in the Windows Registry?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Here's where they're stored on [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) through [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) R2:

#### User Variables

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

#### System Variables

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Comment: Remember to restart your system in order to put your changes into effect.

Comment: You don't need to restart. Just kill Explorer.exe and bring it back alive. It's the parent process for e.g. cmd.exe (when started from the Start menu)

Comment: How about for other processes - like IIS? I'm guessing Explorer.exe isn't the parent for those, so a restart would be needed?

Comment: Processes read in system env variables at the time they start. So with something like IIS, restarting that service should bring in the updated values.

Comment: User path variables (My Documents, AppData, etc) are stored at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74:  Log off is as far as you need to go for applying any env var changes.

Comment: Windows 7 uses the same registry locations.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu & 0x6B6F77616C74, it's worth to mention that if you were doing only local changes, then you should avoid restarting explorer.exe or the whole system. Instead you should use the corresponding control panel applet, or if you are doing it programatically, broadcast the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message with `lParam` set to the string `Environment`. Important part of this process is that notification (which does that control panel applet, or your application after you modify those registry values).

Comment: Is there a possibility to read the `environment variables` from different users? I think `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` only contains the variables of the currently logged in user?

Comment: @gies0r Sure - you would just go to `HKEY_USERS\The-other-users-SID\...` or wherever.  When you look at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` you're looking at an alias for that key for _your_ SID. Permissions might get in your way, though. Hint: The first user created on your machine probably has the SID that ends in -1001; -1000 is for the built-in Administrator account (which, these days, is disabled by default). The three big numbers before that are the "machine ID", which is generated randomly for each Windows install - or comes from your domain controller if you're in a domain.

Comment: According to the docs running this should refresh the environment for the current shell: `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True` https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that there's some environment variables located under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment` as well

Comment: Had an issue with ORACLE_HOME in registry. Setting it here, makes it work like charm.

Answer (score 24):

There is a more efficient way of doing this in Windows 7. SETX is installed by default and supports connecting to other systems.

To modify a remote system's global environment variables, you would use

```
setx /m /s HOSTNAME-GOES-HERE VariableNameGoesHere VariableValueGoesHere
```

This does not require restarting Windows Explorer.

> /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
> the system wide (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
> environment. The default is to set the
> variable under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER
> environment.

> /S     system          Specifies the remote system to connect to.

Comment: Be careful with this, as setx truncates everything after the 1024 charachters!!! https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Answer (score 10):

CMD:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

PowerShell:

```
Get-Item "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
Get-Item HKCU:\Environment
```

Powershell/.NET: (see *[EnvironmentVariableTarget Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget)*)

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables([System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

Answer (score 2):

I always had problems with that, and I made a *getx.bat* script:

```batch
:: getx %envvar% [\m]
:: Reads envvar from user environment variable and stores it in the getxvalue variable
:: with \m read system environment

@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo OFF

@set l_regpath="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment"
@if "\m"=="%2" set l_regpath="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

::REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH /t REG_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"
::@REG QUERY %l_regpath% /v %1 /S

@FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %l_regpath% /v %1 /S') DO (
@  set l_a=%%A
@    if NOT "!l_a!"=="!l_a:    =!" set l_line=!l_a!
)

:: Delimiter is four spaces. Change it to tab \t
@set l_line=!l_line!
@set l_line=%l_line:    =    %

@set getxvalue=

@FOR /F "tokens=3* delims=  " %%A IN ("%l_line%") DO (
@    set getxvalue=%%A
)
@set getxvalue=!getxvalue!
@echo %getxvalue% > getxfile.tmp.txt
@ENDLOCAL

:: We already used tab as a delimiter
@FOR /F "delims=    " %%A IN (getxfile.tmp.txt) DO (
    @set getxvalue=%%A
)
@del getxfile.tmp.txt

@echo ON
```