# Get environment variable for current user and for all users in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

Is there way to determine which environment variables returned by `os.environ` belongs to current user and which one - to all users? I do not want to change it, only get.

**UPD:** I am using Microsoft Windows 7.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: It's `os.environ` not `os.environ()`

Comment: @maxymoo [No](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

Comment: What do you mean by "belongs"? How does an environment variable belong to a user or to all users?

Comment: @Tichodroma there is such thing on Windows

Comment: @Andrey What do you mean by "such thing"?

Comment: @Tichodroma distinction between env variables for user and for all users.

Comment: @Andrey So the question of the OP makes no sense.

Comment: @Tichodroma it makes total sense. If you get a value via `os.environ` you don't know whether this value belongs to this user or to all users.

Comment: @Tichodroma on Windows user has, for example, 2 variable named "PATH" - one applied for all users and second one - applied to current user only and could be customized by any user without admin privileges. So, summary `PATH` is result of concatenation of these two variables (system-wide first, user-wide second).

Comment: So you want to know which environment varialbe has been set by the user?

Comment: @Tichodroma right. What is system-wide `PATH` and what is user-specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can figure it out using standard Python means like `os.environ`. The only way to get user and system variables on Windows is to use registry, you can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

System Variables

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

User variables

You need to access registry with Python to get them.

Answer (score -2):

you can get all the variables by

`import os
print(os.environ)`

this will return you the dictionary type of output with keys as enviornment variables and values as the values of the enviornment variables.

to get the current username:

`print(os.environ['USERNAME'])`

Look for yourself what you want in the dictionary.