# How to get an environment variable of a specified user from a Windows service?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I wrote a Windows service. It is running at the system level. I used the following code to get the logged in user's username. But I want to get an environment variable for that user session. How can I do that?

```
DWORD sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
qInfo() << "session id = " << sessionId;

wchar_t* ppBuffer[100];
DWORD bufferSize;
WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSUserName, ppBuffer, &bufferSize);
qInfo() << "Windows User Name = " << QString::fromWCharArray(*ppBuffer);
```

Comment: The good thing about a logged-in user is that the user profile is loaded. That means you can find them under HKEY_USERS (obviously not HKEY_CURRENT_USER since your service probably doesn't run under that user name). Other than that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry

Comment: Cannot figure out which sub item under HKEY_USERS stands for the specified user. Also, some environment variable contains "%USERPROFILE%", but it looks like not easy to figure out the value of %USERPROFILE% for one sub item under HKEY_USERS.

Comment: It is not loaded, your service runs with whatever account it was configured to run.  You'll have to know the user's SID so you can poke inside HKEY_USERS.  That still only gives you the environment with which a user's session is initialized, it does not tell you anything about environment overrides that the user might have applied.  You'd also have to deal with no users being logged-in or multiple users being logged-in.  Dealing with user sessions in a service is a very bad idea.  Use a plain program that you start with the Run registry key or a shortcut in the Startup folder.

Comment: @HansPassant I think you are right. The problem I face is, the system service will be triggered by some condition to launch the specific program. However, the target program is installed per user. So their installation paths are different. I want the service to launch the active user's program. I'm not clear if that's feasible. I even don't know if 2 users remotely log on to trigger the launching-s separately, what will happen. I will do some test. I have one mechanism to let the service monitor log-on and log-off events. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Assuming that the target program needs to be run as the logged-on user, it would probably be simpler to launch a proxy executable from your service (as the logged-on user) and have *that* executable locate and run the target program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840.aspx) to get the logged in user token for the desired session ID, and then pass that token to [`CreateEnvironmentBlock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270.aspx) to get that user's environment variables.

You can then parse those strings as needed, or pass them (and the token) to 
[`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) to launch a program as the user in the user's session.