# Modify system environment variables

Tags: c, windows, environment-variables

I want to modify my system's environment variables on Windows. I can open the Control Panel's 'Environment Variables' dialog:

[image: dialog]

However, I want to do this programmatically in C. AFAIK, in Unix I can modify the global variable `environ`, but I doubt this would work in Windows.

So, how can I programmatically modify the Windows system environment variables?

Comment: In what language?

Comment: @RobertColumbia tagged [tag:c] and *However, I want to do this programmatically in C.*

Comment: A Google search for *windows set environment variable* turns up [this answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx) as the third result, and that page includes a [link to a code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You're asking for a C solution to a Windows issue and don't want to use `windows.h`? Good luck. The entire API depends on declarations in that file. It's foolish to expect to do anything programmatically with Windows without using it, and if you decide that's what you want to do then you should expect to have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah. I rethought my entire life halfway through writing that comment and deleted it. Sorry.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/573817/694576

Comment: @KenWhite: You have linked to ways to change the calling process' environment. That's not what the UI the OP posted modifies. That UI modifies the global, non-transient environment, stored in the system registry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)

Comment: dupplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148075/6791254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details on how to change the system environment variables are documented under [Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx):

> Calling [**SetEnvironmentVariable**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx) has no effect on the system environment variables. To programmatically add or modify system environment variables, add them to the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment** registry key, then broadcast a [**WM_SETTINGCHANGE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx) message with *lParam* set to the string "Environment". This allows applications, such as the shell, to pick up your updates.

Note that a process needs to be elevated to change values under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MinGW/TDM-GCC you can probably use the same functions used in Unix, `getenv` to get the content of a variable and `setenv` or `putenv`  to write or modify a variable.

If you want to go native you can do this by using 
[`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx). An example on how to use these is also provided. Though they are marked as C++ you can either use a C++ compiler or link using `extern "C"`.

Comment: Be aware that any of those functions change the environment for the *calling process **only***.

Comment: Completely misses the question. The OP is trying to **permanently** alter the environment. Your proposed solution affects the calling process' environment only, and is transient. Once that process dies, the changes are lost. Sorry, -1.