# GetTempPath returns different path in different process

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, boost

GetTempPath returns `C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\` in my application A on Windows 10.

But it returns `C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\2\` in another application B (a dll  hooked in another application prints value of GetTempPath) on same computer. I guess the application B change the temp path.

The boost filesystem behaves the same.

```
auto tempDirPath = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path();
return tempDirPath.native();
```

How does this happen? How could I get exactly the same temp path `C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the windows API. Seams to be a problem with boos. Do you looked into the boost implementation?

Comment: @xMRi Both GetTempPath and boost behaves the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the [`GetTempPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw) API determines the path of the directory designated for temporary files is documented:

> The `GetTempPath` function checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and uses the first path found:

> 1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
>    2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
>    3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
>    4. The Windows directory.

If 2 calls to this API from different processes return different results, then those processes have different environments. By default, a process inherits the environment from its parent process, but [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) allows you to explicitly specify an environment block. Likewise, [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-setenvironmentvariablew) can be used to change an environment variable in the calling process.

You can use tools like [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to inspect the environment of any given process.

Comment: You are right. Do you know a way to get the one in environment of system settings (which the application can not affect)?

Comment: @user1633272: I'm not aware of an API, that allows you to inspect the system-global environment settings. You'd probably have to parse those out of the registry, although this is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to accomplish? Why does it matter, what value you get from `GetTempPath`?

Comment: A injected dll to target application and my application need to negotiate a path to export file/read file. Currently I'm using temp path to construct the file path, but the temp path is changed by the target application on one of my clients computer.

Comment: @user1633272: If those processes need to agree on a location, they should communicate that location with each other (pipes, shared memory, etc.). Relying on state outside your control isn't going to work reliably.

Comment: My initial idea is using a filename constructed by process id under temp path. A communication mechanism should work, just looks overkill. I will try to read the value from registry or construct it by user name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry