# GetTempPath of user on Windows

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

As this question [GetTempPath returns different path in different process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832206/gettemppath-returns-different-path-in-different-process#50832616) described, the GetTempPath could be changed by a process.

Do you know a way to get the temp path for a user (which is not affected by specific application) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no user specific temp directory and there is no [known folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) constant for it. You could argue that `%LocalAppData%\Temp` is the default but you should not assume that this is true.

A user might set their %Temp% to a different drive (RAM disk etc.) and apply it to all processes or they might run a specific application with a different %Temp% because their normal %Temp% location does not have enough free space etc.

The `GetTempPath` function already has other backup locations it tries if %Temp% is invalid so there is no reason for you to second-guess it. If you need a per-user folder that is shared by multiple processes then you should use a folder under `FOLDERID_LocalAppData`.

Comment: Can I assume HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TMP the default location for current user?

Comment: It is probably safe enough, just remember to fall back to TEMP if the first value is not set.

Comment: Yes, get first available value of TMP and TEMP, then use ExpandEnvironmentStrings to finalize the path.