# Windows: get all *current* environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Goal: from my application I want to launch arbitrary commands, e.g. `cmd.exe` with the current environment variables, e.g. while my application runs and the user modifies the path, launching the terminal should get the new path.

According to my understanding, if a process is launched, it will receive the environment variable values from its launching process (either inherit or individual values). On Windows it is possible to access the **latest** values of environment variables by reading registry entries (see [question "Where are environment variables stored in registry?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-registry)). They are stored in the registry as they are configured, e.g. `Comspec`: `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`. Hence you will need the value of other environment variables like `SystemRoot` to expand them.

Unfortunately, when taking a look at all environment variables my process received from the parent process with the ones I can read from the registry, there seems to be a large difference. I just can't use the inherited environment variables and replace the registry-configured ones with their values, because then a custom environment variable that the user deleted during the runtime of my application would prevail.

Where can I find out which environment variables Windows by default provides, e.g. `SystemRoot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateEnvironmentBlock` WINAPI can be used to obtain the current environment variables. Its `bInherit` parameter lets you choose whether to inherit variables from your process or not.

C++ snippet that demonstrates it:

```
HANDLE userToken = 0;
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, &userToken))
{
    _tprintf(_T("ERROR: OpenProcessToken"));
    return 1;
}

void* envVars = 0;
if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(&envVars, userToken, TRUE))
{
    _tprintf(_T("ERROR: CreateEnvironmentBlock"));
    return 1;
}

const wchar_t* iter = (const wchar_t*)envVars;
while (*iter)
{
    _tprintf(_T("ENV: %s\n"), iter);
    iter += _tcslen(iter) + 1;
}

DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envVars);
```

Comment: In case somebody stumbled here looking for a way to get all environment variables active right now in the current process: use `GetEnvironmentStrings()`.